# css relative div show space in auto height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I need to show relative div over normal div:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">normal text added</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.inner {
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
    bottom:50px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index:10;
}
```

This worked. But i need to show last `div` after `inner`. In action, i see a red space for relative margin. How do I fix this ?

Problem picture:

[image]

i need to this:

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs1kv2wu/)

Comment: You need to restructure your question and make what you're asking clearer.

Comment: Not able to understand your problem, can you please elaborate in clear words.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the `bottom:50px;` from the `.relative` rule with a code sample below.

I also created a new "to work with demo" at fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/3Lhj2sns/, where we can test until we reach what you want.

```css
.inner {
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 relative">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>
                
            </div>
           
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">normal text added</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: u remove  `bottom:50px;` i need to this. please see my edit.

Comment: @P.O.P Updated again ... as how your "edit picture" shows

Comment: why we add `relative-padd`?!!! i need to overlap relative div like edit picture. see edited fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/xs1kv2wu/1/

Comment: Do you say that the ".inner with red background" should be 50 px less high than the 3 ".relative" together and those 3 should be "pushed up" above the ".inner with red background" and kind of overlap the other elements "container", "row" and "col-md-12" ??

Comment: And if so, why do you need to do that? .. Can you show a whole page/picture of page so I can understand better. There might be a way simpler solution than doing like that.